# How to validate a text using regular expression in java script?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression to validate the dates and it works fine, this is it

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```

But I want to validate it using the javascript. I tried with this

```
var  ck_effectivedate= /^(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;

function radtxtbxNewEffectiveDateOnBlur(sender, eventArgs) {

  if (!ck_effectivedate.test(sender.get_value())) {
    alert('matches');
   }
   else
   {
     alert('does not match');
   }

}
```

But, the regular expression is not working, because of the presence of `/` character in my regular expression which is also used to encapsulate the regular expression in java script.

If I remove the `/` character then it works, but I want to use that in my string.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to escape the special characters with a backslash `\`:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$
```

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).